# Display Calculated Date in French using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I created a macro to calculate a date value then convert (for display on document) to French:

```vb
Sub FrenchFutureDate()
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(CDate(ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("RREG_Registr_File_GSFTDateReceived").Value) + 30, "d, mmmm, yyyy")
    Selection.LanguageID = wdFrench
End Sub
```

NOTE: original / baseline date is being passed as a mailmerge value.

We would like to change the function to use the current date.

I swapped the mail merge field reference to date (see below).

Problem is the date no longer displays in French just English.

```vb
Sub FrenchFutureDate()          
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(Date + 30, "mmmm d, yyyy")
    Selection.LanguageID = wdFrench
End Sub
```

Comment: Setting the language of a selection or a range only sets the spell check language. It does not translate text. `Format` can only return a date formatted according to the computer's regional settings.

Comment: What you can do is build you own function to convert english day to french day

Comment: Is this Word or Excel? Both are tagged.

Comment: You could, of course, do this in the Word mailmerge main document without the need for a macro... See *Calculate a day, date, month and year, using n days delay* and *Date and Time Calculations In A Mailmerge* in my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function similar to this, just replace with the French month names and rename the function to, say, `MonthNameFrench`:

```vb
' Returns the English month name for the passed month number.
' Accepted numbers are 1 to 12. Other values will raise an error.
' If Abbreviate is True, the returned name is abbreviated.
'
' 2015-11-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MonthNameInvariant( _
    ByVal Month As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean) _
    As String
    
    Const AbbreviatedLength As Integer = 3
    
    Dim MonthName( _
        MinMonthValue To _
        MaxMonthValue)      As String
    Dim Name                As String
    
    If Not IsMonth(Month) Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Non-localized (invariant) month names.
    MonthName(1) = "January"
    MonthName(2) = "February"
    MonthName(3) = "March"
    MonthName(4) = "April"
    MonthName(5) = "May"
    MonthName(6) = "June"
    MonthName(7) = "July"
    MonthName(8) = "August"
    MonthName(9) = "September"
    MonthName(10) = "October"
    MonthName(11) = "November"
    MonthName(12) = "December"
    
    If Abbreviate = True Then
        Name = Left(MonthName(Month), AbbreviatedLength)
    Else
        Name = MonthName(Month)
    End If
    
    MonthNameInvariant = Name

End Function
```

It is taken from module `DateText.bas` in my project [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

The constants can be found in module [DateBase.bas](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date/blob/master/DateBase.bas).

Comment: Fyi Instead of assigning all twelve month names one by one, you may get an array of *French* month names simply via `months = [Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"[$-80C]mmmm")]`; to force the English *pendants* independant from system options change the text format prefix to `[$-409]`. @Gustav

Comment: You might consider to integrate the undeclared Min|MaxMonthValue and IsMonth func in the post to make your code reproducable for anybody.

Comment: @T.M.: Right, but the function is intended not to be Excel-specific but generic VBA. Also, added a link to the constants. Thanks.

Comment: Probably OP intends it as you said; as the question, however tags refer to Excel, too I posted an Excel function anyway. 'v,  @Gustav+:)

Answer (score 0):

As long as Word's date field formatting supports the language you want to use (French in your case) you can do it this way:

```
Sub InsertDatePlus30FR()
Dim f As Word.Field
Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldQuote, """" & Format(Date + 30, "YYYY-MM-DD") & """ \@ ""MMMM, D, YYYY""", False)
f.Code.LanguageID = wdFrench
f.Update
' If you want to remove the field, uncomment the following line
' f.Unlink
Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

(NB, when you construct a date in this way in Word, Word *always* interprets the "NNNN-NN-NN" format as YYYY-MM-DD, never YYYY-DD-MM - assuming it's a date).

Comment: Thank you Jonsson.  The above worked perfectly.   Not to say the others suggestions didn't / wouldn't just first one I tried.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is also tagged as `Excel` you might consider to use the following function to get French month names:

**Function `mois()`**

- a) Uses (*an abbreviated brackets method of*) formula **evaluation** to get a 1-based 2-dimensional array of all French month names (see formatting prefix `[$-80C]`) and
- b) simply returns the month string indicated by the first argument `indx`, either in full length or abbreviated conform to system options (2nd argument `abbrev`).

```
Option Explicit

Function mois(ByVal indx As Long, Optional ByVal abbrev = False) As String
'Meth: Excel evaluation based on column sequence
'Purp: return French month name
'0) escape clause for invalid indices
    If indx > 12 Or indx < 1 Then Mois = "?": Exit Function
'a) get 1-based 1-dim array of french months name
    Dim months
    If abbrev Then
        months = [Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"[$-80C]mmm")]
    Else    ' full length
        months = [Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"[$-80C]mmmm")]
    End If
'b) return function result
    mois = months(indx)
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
    Debug.Print Mois(4)       ' ~~> avril
    Debug.Print Mois(4, True) ' ~~> avr.
```